# How to execute JavaScript code after a Store event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ext.net

I have a store on my page:

```
<ext:Store 
    ID="Store1" 
    runat="server" 
    OnAfterStoreChanged="Store1_AfterChanged" 
    OnRefreshData="MyData_Refresh">
    <Reader>
        <ext:JsonReader>
            <Fields>                                    
                <ext:RecordField Name="Name" />
                <ext:RecordField Name="Id" />             
            </Fields>
        </ext:JsonReader>
    </Reader>
</ext:Store>
```

I need to run JavaScript code after the `Store1_AfterChanged` event executes. If it were defined via the `DirectEvents` section, I could use the `After` attribute.
How to do it when the event is defined this way (as an attribute of the `Store`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I can execute a JS function call from the C# event handler by calling

> X.Call("function_name", arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Try to define script via ResourceManager in Event method:

```
X.ResourceManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock("After", "Ext.Msg.alert('After');");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can register any script with

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```

method from your code behind

**update:**
then maybe this link may help:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=256

Comment: I do not need a startup script; I need to call a JS function after one specific event was executed.